# How to call a Biztalk net.TCP service from Raw TCP request?

Tags: wcf, oracle, tcp, biztalk

I have written a net.tcp based service in Biztalk 2006 R2 and it listens at a location,

```
http://localhost:5060/WCFTcpService
```

I need to call this service by using Raw TCP request. i.e.
I don't want to create a proxy class and consume it in a .NET client application. 
How can I be able to do this?
The real scenario is that an Oracle Stored procedure will be used to communicate with this service and the only way I am allowed to call this service is to send a TCP request to the Biztalk server that is hosting the service.
Any help or tips would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question. See the URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546004/how-to-use-socket-based-client-with-wcf-net-tcp-service

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you may need to call an external program from Oracle, if I understand what you're asking about. Not sure of your Oracle version, but mostly the later versions tighten security, but the functionality is there.

Look at [this site](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/PL_SQL/PLSQL_1.shtml) for a basic primer. More info is [here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/PL_SQL/PLSQL_17.shtml). [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ex.htm) are sometimes useful, too. All this and more can be found using a [google search on oracle external procedure.](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=oracle+external+procedure&btnG=Search)