# How to use socket based client with WCF (net.tcp) service?

Tags: .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

I have developed a WCF service that uses the net.tcp adapter and listens to a specific port. I want to connect to that service using a normal .net client that uses sockets to send data to the port and listens to responses.
When I try to send data to this service, I get the error: "The existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host".
However, i am able to connect with the service by another client which uses the Address/Binding/Contracts of the WCF service.
Is there a way that enables me to communicate with a WCF service by using an ordinary socket based client?

Comment: To be sure that everybody understands what you are trying to do here... Would you please clarify if you are trying to use the built-in sockets programming facility within .NET to connect to a Net.Tcp WCF service and vice versa?

Comment: EnocNRoll, You are absolutely right. 
I am trying to use a socket based client to communicate a net.tcp based WCF service.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The key decision is whether or not to make the WCF service conform to the socket client or whether to make the socket client conform to the WCF service.

It will be simplest to attempt to conform to the WCF service, rather than trying to implement something custom within WCF, which is never easy.  At the bottom of the Other Resources section below you will see a link that describes the message inspection that is necessary in order to attempt to conform to a WCF service.

Having said that, .NET sockets do not natively communicate with WCF.

Any attempt to do so will require custom programming on the WCF side of things.

Whether you are using TcpClient or raw sockets in .NET to connect to and communicate with WCF does not matter.  Any such interoperability must be handled with custom logic within WCF.  Note that Net.Tcp is a custom transport protocol.  It is not technically using TCP in the same way that the TcpClient is.

For example, UDP is very commonly used by socket servers in the Linux world.  WCF does not provide a built-in UDP transport.  However, there is a UDP sample for WCF that implements UDP for WCF.  Unfortunately, that sample does not illustrate communicating to and from a non-WCF UPD socket server.

I have an outstanding question that is rather detailed where I explain my effort to get sample code to generically be testable for using UDP...

[Is it possible to make the WcfTestClient work for custom transport channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484717/error-externally-testing-wcf-udp-custom-transport-channel-sample-from-the-windows)

Nobody has answered my question yet.  So, if you succeed in making this work, I am very interested.  My case was driven by a desire for the WCF Service to be able to call out to a UDP socket server running on Linux without having to clutter my service with non-WCF coding.  I don't want to mix approaches.

**Other Resources...**

- Choosing a Transport
  *This article states that "The WCF TCP transport is optimized for the
  scenario where both ends of the
  communication are using WCF".*

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx
- Trying to connect a non-WCF client to a WCF service
  that uses the BasicHttpBinding.
   *The
  developer ends up writing custom code
  via the WebClient (as opposed to
  TcpClient).*
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c2d72c2d-c095-4ae1-b8ae-d15f32a4e0be/
- WCF vs. Raw .NET Sockets
  *The answer points out that TCP + binary serialization or UDP + binary
  serialization might be needed.  There
  is a UDP binding sample, as I
  mentioned above.*
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c0520111-c1ca-4ffd-a4e0-ac68e86130ee/
- Writing Custom Requests to Simple WCF
  Services
  *The author explains how to figure out the format of the message that
  needs to be sent to the service, so
  that the TcpClient or other non-WCF
  sockets client can send the write
  information to the WCF service. The
  implication here is that you are not
  attempting to conform the WCF
  service, but rather you are forcing
  the socket client to do the heavy
  lifting.  Even so, you not get the
  built-in advantages of the WCF
  bindings if you are expecting
  that.*
  http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/01/13/writing-custom-requests-to-simple-wcf-services.aspx

Comment: but you criticised the wonderful WCF, so therefore you need to be taken outside and shot :) - have +1 from me though.

Comment: Thanks, I try to make my answer useful and I always update them if they are incorrect in any way.  I view them as references for my personal knowledge also, not simply for points on StackOverflow.

Comment: Great answer EnocNRoll. Very impressive. A definite +1 ;)

Comment: I upvoted the question so now you have enough reputation to upvote.  You had only 11, but 15 are needed.  Now you have 21.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: So go ahead and try out your new power by reattempting to upvote my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: does wcf make use raw .net sockets under the hood ?

Answer (score 6):

The Net.TCP binding uses a custom wire-level framing format that is not really documented, though Nicholas Allen started a series of blog posts on the topic recently. The series start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2009/01/19/message-framing-part-1.aspx

To be honest, Net.TCP is really, currently, more useful for WCF to WCF communication. if you want to interop with a custom TCP format that you need to handle, you're much better off either using raw sockets or creating your own custom WCF transport channel (which might not be trivial, btw)

Comment: It is well documented, see [MC-NMF] .NET Message Framing Protocol Specification.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

did you enable the WCF Tracing? Because if you do and you get the following message: **"The service does not allow you to log on anonymously."** then it is (usually) a security setting problem.

In this case disable the security mode for your binding:

```
<netTcpBinding>
   <binding name="MyCustomBinding"> 
      <security mode="None" /> 
   </binding> 
</netTcpBinding>
```

But better would be to work with certificates.