# Is it possible to communicate with an external system over TCP/IP using WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, fix-protocol

We are building a system that interacts with an external system over TCP/IP using the [FIX Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol).  I've used WCF to communicate from client to server, where I had control over both client and server, but never to an external TCP/IP based system.  Is this possible with WCF?  If so, could the community provide links for me to get started and faced in the right direction?

Unfortunately I do not have much more information that what is supplied above, as we are still in the early early planning stages.  What we know is that we have an external vendor whose system will communicate with our system over TCP/IP.  We would like to use this as a learning opportunity and learn WCF.

Comment: +1... a good question for those who want to mix WCF and TCP/IP with sockets..

Comment: We've heard that WCF can communicate over many types of bindings and never have to change the programming model at all.  But if we can only use WCF with systems where we have control over both connected systems, perhaps we have misunderstood the value of WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, at least it won't be easy to set it up because you don't  know the communication protocol of the other end, except for it's TCP and accept FIX tags.

Why don't you within WCF application open TCP connection a SOCKET. That should do the trick in a simpler manner.

Comment: why not just use a socket and not use WCF at all? I don't see how WCF helps if I am using a socket.  Perhaps I don't understand what a SOCKET is.  Do you mean a TCP/IP socket?

Comment: Exactly, I would NOT use wcf at all, but I presume he has more than just what he specified thus making SOA model implemented with WCF. I think OP should provide more info about his problem

Answer (score 3):

Possible? Possibly yes, but it's going to take some work.

For starters, you will need to write a custom WCF Transport Channel that handles the specifics of your TCP/IP based protocols (i.e. you'll need to write all the socket handling code and hook that into the WCF channel model). This is because the TCP channel in WCF isn't for this kind of work, but uses a relatively proprietary and undocumented wire protocol.

I'm not familiar enough with FIX to say how complex it would be, but there are some gotchas when writing WCF channels and documentation in that area isn't great.

The second part you'll need to deal with is message encoding. To WCF, all messages are XML. That is, once a message is passed on to the WCF stack, it has to look like an XML infoset at runtime. FIX doesn't use XML (afaik), so you'll need to adapt it a bit.

There are two ways you can go around it:

1. The easy way: Assume the server/client will use a specific interface and format for the data, and have your channel do all the hard work of translating the FIX messages to/from that format. The simplest example of this would be to have your WCF code use a simple service contract with one method taking a string and then just encapsulating the FIX message string into the XML format that satisfies the data contract serializer for that contract. The user code would still need to deal with decoding the FIX format later, though.
2. Do all the hard work in a custom WCF MessageEncoder. It's a bit more complex, but potentially cleaner and more reusable (and you could do more complex things like better streaming and so on).

The big question though is whether this is worth it. What is your reasoning for wanting to use WCF for this? Leveraging the programming model? I think that's an important consideration, but also keep in mind that the abstractions that WCF provides come at a price. In particular, some aspects of WCF can be problematic if you have very real-time requirements, which I understand is common in the kind of financial environment you're looking at.

If that's the case, it may very well be that you'd be better served by skipping WCF and sticking a little closer to the metal. You'll need to do the socket work anyway, so that's something to consider there.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* so. I have a system that I *almost* got working that was supposed to do almost exactly that (WCF over HTTP from the internet). The server provider seemed to not want to allow it thought so you will need the right permissions on that end to make it work.

Up shot: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

Not really - Ms didn't make the TCP/IP connection handler to talk to non-WCF services, they assumed you'd write a Web Service to do that.

This is discussed [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546004/how-to-use-socket-based-client-with-wcf-net-tcp-service).