# How to use simple TCP/IP sockets connection over Net.TCP WCF binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, tcp, net.tcp

How to use simple [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite) sockets connections over/with Net.TCP [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) binding? 
Idea is – We have a web service with Net.TCP binding on some URL, port. We want to take advantage of the WCF address model and simplicity of socket connections. 
So can we use simple TCP/IP sockets connection over/with Net.TCP WCF binding?

**If yes.**
 What do I need?

- MSDN if there is any help on this.
- Open Source Libs/wrappers.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it.

---

**If no**: I need know where did you get the information from (link to MSDN or other official WCF information resource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this - [How to use socket based client with WCF (net.tcp) service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546004/how-to-use-socket-based-client-with-wcf-net-tcp-service)

The way I see it you want to feed from wcf service with a socket object (correct me if I got it wrong)... I haven't done it (just read it)

Comment: There is no doubt that there is lot of information on this topic in general but no exact answer to this question. Only general ideas and examples on bacikHttpBinding not on Net.TCP(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this, but you would need to implement the .NET Message Framing Protocol used by NetTcpBinding. Documentation is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219293(PROT.10).aspx