# Dynamically invoke a method over a socket

Tags: c#, sockets, reflection, methods, invoke

I have 2 pc's with some software, now I need one pc to execute a method on another pc, now I've searched high and low but could not find anything on how to do this. I could do this with writing my own little interface that serializes the arguments, method name and return objects and sending this over a socket then deserialize this execute the method using reflection, and return an result object over the socket. But I would like someone else's opinion before I start writing something that is much easier another way.

- Send multiple arguments (they will all be received and send as an object)
- Return an object
- serialize back an exception object if any has occurred

I have not done anything in serializing objects and sending them over a socket, but are all standard objects serializable? Like a `List<> array[] float dateTime`?

I hope to have explained this ok, if not I'm sorry and ask what is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched the internet for examples and pasted together some code, i'm posting it here if somone needs it too. This is a dirty code but it works, the InvokeMethod is on the client side, and the startIBC is what needs to be started on each server:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IBlissRequest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        object SystemRequest(string InstanceName, string MethodName, params object[] Parameters);
    }

    public class BlissRequest : IBlissRequest
    {
        public object SystemRequest(string InstanceName, string MethodName, params object[] Parameters)
        {
            return System21.BlissProcessingUnit.BPU.RequestFromIBC(InstanceName, MethodName, Parameters);
        }
    }

public static object InvokeMethod(string targetIpAddress, string InstanceName, string MethodName, params object[] Parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                var ep = "net.tcp://" + targetIpAddress + ":9985/IBC";

                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

                ChannelFactory<IBlissRequest> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IBlissRequest>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep));

                IBlissRequest pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

                return pipeProxy.SystemRequest(InstanceName, MethodName, Parameters);
            }
            catch 
            {
                BPUConsole.WriteLine(BPUConsole.WriteSource.IBC, "Unable to execute method: '" + MethodName +"' on Instance: '"+InstanceName+"' becouse IBC is unable to connect to: "+ targetIpAddress);
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to: " + targetIpAddress);
            }
        }

        public static void StartIBC()
        {
            var uri = "net.tcp://" + BlissProcessingUnit.BPUInformation.LocalIpAddresses[0] + ":9985";
            Console.WriteLine("Opening connection on: " + uri);

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BlissRequest), new Uri[] { new Uri(uri) });

            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IBlissRequest), binding, "IBC");

            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service is available. " + "Press <ENTER> to exit.");

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create service WCF and config WCF to work over TCP.

This will give you most  things 'out of the box' (serialize /deserialize, open/close socket )

There are good examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx), [here](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2009/08/05/building-a-really-simple-wcf-p2p-application/) and good reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546004/how-to-use-socket-based-client-with-wcf-net-tcp-service)

Comment: I have searched for examples for this, but i canot find anything i understand completely, what i need is that there are multiple comuters on a network that can execute methods on the other comuters, but i have not found any example that does this over the network that is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like remote procedure calling (RPC). RPC allows you to create a single object on a server which clients can interact with as if it were a local object (so completely avoid the need to deal with sockets). Alternatively each client can also create its own unique server object to interact with.

A full implementation of RPC can be found in the network library [networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net). The following code snippet is taken from the available RPC example and uses an object of type `MathClass` that can perform simple maths calculations.

The object exists server side:

```
//Register a single object server side called "Calculator"
RemoteProcedureCalls.Server.RegisterInstanceForPublicRemoteCall<MathClass, IMath>(new MathClass(), "Calculator");
```

On the client side:

```
//Get a reference to the remote object named "Calculator"
IMath calc = RemoteProcedureCalls.Client.CreateProxyToPublicNamedInstance<IMath>(connection, "Calculator", out instanceId);
//We can now use the calculator object as if it were local
//The following WriteLine outputs '12' where the calculation was performed on the server
Console.WriteLine(calc.Multiply(4, 3));
```

Disclaimer: I have to add that I am a developer for this library.