# Is it possible to send TCP message using Webservices Asp.net or need WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, tcp, wcf-binding

I need to develop a WebSevice which takes its input and forwards this input using TCP.

Is it possible for Asp.net Webservices ? Or Should I use WCF etc..

I have to know if it is possible to create a web service that should be like a bridge between the two: it waits for an incoming request, forwards it to the required TCP port.

Simple samples are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think Asp.net is possible to use TCP , but I think you should use WCF.
This will give you most  things 'out of the box' (serialize /deserialize, open/close socket )

There are good examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx), [here](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2009/08/05/building-a-really-simple-wcf-p2p-application/) and good reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546004/how-to-use-socket-based-client-with-wcf-net-tcp-service)

Comment: I had just develop WCF service. 
It was so easy to send message over TPC.
I used [tcp sender sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) to send tcp message.